# deployment on elastic beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, ebcli

i am trying to deploy my django app on aws using the awsebcli amd i am trying to run the eb init command and i am getting this error

```
DELL@DESKTOP-LOONUF5 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/kennedy_logistics (main)
$ eb status
ERROR: This directory has not been set up with the EB CLI
You must first run "eb init".

DELL@DESKTOP-LOONUF5 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/kennedy_logistics (main)
$ eb logs
ERROR: This directory has not been set up with the EB CLI
You must first run "eb init".

DELL@DESKTOP-LOONUF5 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/kennedy_logistics (main)
$ eb init

Select a default region
1) us-east-1 : US East (N. Virginia)
2) us-west-1 : US West (N. California)
3) us-west-2 : US West (Oregon)
4) eu-west-1 : EU (Ireland)
5) eu-central-1 : EU (Frankfurt)
6) ap-south-1 : Asia Pacific (Mumbai)
7) ap-southeast-1 : Asia Pacific (Singapore)
8) ap-southeast-2 : Asia Pacific (Sydney)
9) ap-northeast-1 : Asia Pacific (Tokyo)
10) ap-northeast-2 : Asia Pacific (Seoul)
11) sa-east-1 : South America (Sao Paulo)
12) cn-north-1 : China (Beijing)
13) cn-northwest-1 : China (Ningxia)
14) us-east-2 : US East (Ohio)
15) ca-central-1 : Canada (Central)
16) eu-west-2 : EU (London)
17) eu-west-3 : EU (Paris)
18) eu-north-1 : EU (Stockholm)
19) eu-south-1 : EU (Milano)
20) ap-east-1 : Asia Pacific (Hong Kong)
21) me-south-1 : Middle East (Bahrain)
22) il-central-1 : Middle East (Israel)
23) af-south-1 : Africa (Cape Town)
24) ap-southeast-3 : Asia Pacific (Jakarta)
25) ap-northeast-3 : Asia Pacific (Osaka)
(default is 3): 1

ERROR: MaxRetriesError - Max retries exceeded for ResponseParserErrorsUnable to parse response (no element found: line 1, column 0), invalid XML received. Further retries may succeed:
b''
Unable to parse response (no element found: line 1, column 0), invalid XML received. Further retries may succeed:
b''
Unable to parse response (no element found: line 1, column 0), invalid XML received. Further retries may succeed:
b''
Unable to parse response (no element found: line 1, column 0), invalid XML received. Further retries may succeed:
b''
Unable to parse response (no element found: line 1, column 0), invalid XML received. Further retries may succeed:
b''
Unable to parse response (no element found: line 1, column 0), invalid XML received. Further retries may succeed:
b''
Unable to parse response (no element found: line 1, column 0), invalid XML received. Further retries may succeed:
b''
Unable to parse response (no element found: line 1, column 0), invalid XML received. Further retries may succeed:
b''
Unable to parse response (no element found: line 1, column 0), invalid XML received. Further retries may succeed:
b''
Unable to parse response (no element found: line 1, column 0), invalid XML received. Further retries may succeed:
b''
```